# Creating an inner object

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, I want to create an inner object.

I defined an object like this:

```
var Translations = {
    acceptConditions: 'Please approve the agreement',
    isEmptyUser: 'User Name'
}
```

But how can I defined an inner object?

I tried:

```
var Translations = {

    var innerTranslations = {

        acceptConditions: 'Please approve the agreement',
        isEmptyUser: 'User Name'
    }
}
```

Also tried with function, cant make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an inner object, you need to give access to it:

```
var Translations = {

    innerTranslations: {

        acceptConditions: 'Please approve the agreement',
        isEmptyUser: 'User Name'
    }
}
```

This sets up a property on `Translations` named `innerTranslations`.  And can then be used like this:

```
Translations.innerTranslations.acceptConditions;
```

Comment: Works, Thanks for the help, don't have enough rep to up you :]

Comment: If it is an answer to your question, you can accept it. :)

Comment: 15 min to wait... I got some upvotes so i voted you, thx again

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to convert it to **JSON** object. **innerTranslations**  property is now kind of inner representation.

```
var Translations = {
  innerTranslations : {
    acceptConditions: 'Please approve the agreement',
    isEmptyUser: 'User Name'
   }
}
```